# Why does dcast not accept x[length(x)]?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

I've been struggling to get `dcast` to aggregate by taking the last element. Here's an example:

```
x <- data.table::data.table(foo = "bar", value = c(1, 0))
x

#    foo value
# 1: bar     1
# 2: bar     0
```

```
data.table::dcast(x, ... ~ foo, fun.aggregate = function(x) x[length(x)])

# Error: Aggregating function(s) should take vector inputs and return a single value (length=1).
# However, function(s) returns length!=1. This value will have to be used to fill any missing
# combinations, and therefore must be length=1. Either override by setting the 'fill' argument
# explicitly or modify your function to handle this case appropriately.
```

This also happens with the `reshape2` version of `dcast`, and if using a `data.frame` instead of a `data.table`.

There are ways I can get this to work. For example, I can use

```
data.table::dcast(x, ... ~ foo, fun.aggregate = function(x) rev(x)[1L])

#    . bar
# 1: .   0
```

and get the expected result. The `dplyr::last()` function also works, `data.table::last()` does not.

However, what I'm interested is in why using `x[length(x)]` doesn't work. If I put intermediate print commands in the aggregation function to work out what's happening, I get the following:

```
data.table::dcast(x, ... ~ foo,
                  fun.aggregate = function(x) {print(x); print(length(x)); 5L}, value.var = "value")

# numeric(0)
# [1] 0
# [1] 1 0
# [1] 2
#    . bar
# 1: .   5
```

This suggests that `dcast` is iterating over a value of `foo` that is not in the table, and can't exist elsewhere since `foo` is a simple character vector, not a factor vector. What's happening?

`R` version: 3.6.0
`data.table` version: 1.12.2

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Sure, I've added it as the output for using rev(x)[1L].

Comment: Instead of doing it in the `dcast`, can't you subset first and then do the dcast

Comment: I can, yes, I'll go back to my actual use case and see if that helps. The question is more why doing it with x[length(x)] doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You can use `last`

Comment: Only the `dplyr` `last`, the `data.table` `last` gives the same error.

Comment: It is found in both packages

Comment: use `function(x) x[max(length(x), 1)]` to ensure non-zero length output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that both `data.table::dcast.data.table()` and `reshape2::dcast()` expect the aggregating function to return a length 1 value for length 0 input. Both functions try to get a "default value" to use by calling the aggregating function with a length 0 argument.

The relevant part of the data.table code is [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/1da76240e8291c104e7fc0aed86b5828531aa41c/R/fcast.R#L171-L173) and looks like this:

```
fill.default = suppressWarnings(dat[0L][, eval(fun.call)])
if (nrow(fill.default) != 1L) stop(errmsg, call.=FALSE)
```

reshape2 calls `vaggregate()` from plyr, that has a similar part [here](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/blob/fe192412748d1ccb6d524caeb5bcf2b5c474fd46/R/vaggregate.r#L48):

```
.default <- .fun(.value[0], ...)
```

So in the case of `x[length(x)]` the default value that both functions obtain is essentially:

```r
last <- function(x) x[length(x)]
last(numeric())
#> numeric(0)
```

That is, a length 0 vector. But both functions require the default value to have length 1, thus the error.

Finally, `dplyr::last()` works because it returns `NA` for a length 0 input:

```r
dplyr::last(numeric())
#> [1] NA
```